# Filter data from Google Sheet on a leaflet map by group

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, leaflet

I'm trying to create a map with markers using data from Google Sheet using leaflet. I managed that but there are some bugs that I can't fix:

1. Filter by group - I can filter by group, but only one marker is displayed for each selected group, even tho I have multiple data in the same group. Here attached a photo of the output
   [image]
2. Replacing markers - I wanted the map to show markers that correspond to the selected group only, i.e., if I select Male, then only show only data in the group Male, and vice versa. But for now, once I select a group (for example Male), when I attempt to select another group (Female), the marker for Male group still exists.
   [image]

Here is the sample data from Google Sheet
[image]

Here's my code:
Apps script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('map');
}

function getAddress(group) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var groupSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var getLastRow = groupSheet.getLastRow();  
  var return_array = [];
  if (group === 'All'){
    return groupSheet.getRange(2, 1, getLastRow - 1, 5).getValues();  
  } else {
    for (var i = 2; i<= getLastRow; i++){
      if (groupSheet.getRange(i,3).getValue() === group){
        return_array.push(groupSheet.getRange(i,1,1,5).getValues());
      }
    }
    return return_array;
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divfilter" class="col12" onchange="onSelect()">
      Select a group:  
        <div class="col4">
            <input type="radio" name="filGroup" value="All" checked>All
        </div>
        <div class="col4">
            <input type="radio" name="filGroup" value="Male" >Male
        </div>
        <div class="col4">
            <input type="radio" name="filGroup" value="Female" >Female
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="viewmap"></div>
    
<script>
  var map_init = L.map('viewmap',{
      center: [4.042649, 103.624396],
      zoom:8
  });
  var basemap = L.tileLayer ('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo (map_init);

  function onSelect(){
    var map = map_init;
    var group = document.querySelector('input[name="filGroup"]:checked').value;
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar){
      console.log(ar);
      ar.forEach(function(item, index){
        var group = document.querySelector('input[name="filGroup"]:checked').value;

        if (group === 'All'){
          var marker = L.marker([item[0], item[1]]).addTo(map);
          marker.bindPopup('<div id="text"><p>Name: ' + item[3] + '<br>DOB: ' + item[4] + '</p></div>' ); 
        } else{
          var marker = L.marker([item[index][0], item[index][1]]).addTo(map);  
          marker.bindPopup('<div id="text"><p>Name: ' + item[index][3] + '<br>DOB: ' + item[index][4] + '</p></div>' ); 
        }  
      });
    }).getAddress(group);    
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>


<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #viewmap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #text {
      font-family:Georgia,'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }
</style>
```

I'd be most grateful if anyone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first attempt at maps but I tried it and it works.

Change your files accordingly.

HTML_TestMap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
      body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }

      #viewmap {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
      }

      #text {
        font-family:Georgia,'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="divfilter" class="col12" onchange="onSelect()">
      Select a group:  
        <div class="col4">
            <input type="radio" name="filGroup" value="All" checked>All
        </div>
        <div class="col4">
            <input type="radio" name="filGroup" value="Male" >Male
        </div>
        <div class="col4">
            <input type="radio" name="filGroup" value="Female" >Female
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="viewmap"></div>
    
    <script>
      var map_init = null;
      var basemap = null;
      var map_markers = [];

      (function () {
        try {
          map_init = L.map('viewmap',{
            center: [4.042649, 103.624396],
            zoom:8
          });
          basemap = L.tileLayer ('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          }).addTo (map_init);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      })();

      function onSelect(){
        var map = map_init;
        var group = document.querySelector('input[name="filGroup"]:checked').value;
    
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(ar){
            try {
              map_markers.forEach( marker => marker.remove() );
              map_markers = [];
              ar.forEach(function(item, index){
                var group = document.querySelector('input[name="filGroup"]:checked').value;

                var marker = L.marker([item[0], item[1]]).addTo(map);
                marker.bindPopup('<div class="mapFlag" id="text"><p>Name: ' + item[3] + '<br>DOB: ' + item[4] + '</p></div>' );
                map_markers.push(marker);
              });
            }
            catch(err) {
              alert(err);
            }
          }
        ).getAddress(group);  
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function getAddress(group) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var groupSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = groupSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift(); // remove headers
    if( group !== 'All' ) {
      values = values.filter( row => row[2] === group )
    }
    return values;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: I made a small correction to my script.  I removed ` var map = map_init;` from `onSelect`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I copied the codes but it's not working for me. There's an error message `ReferenceError: map is not defined` when I clicked on any of the radio buttons. I tried to narrow down the source by changing the error message, and it appears that it's from the try-catch within `function(ar)`

Comment: Might I also ask what is `class="mapFlag" ` in `marker.bindPopup()`?

Comment: I'm sorry I should not have deleted the line `var map = map_init;`.  I mistakenly thought it wasn't used.

Comment: I missed out on that too! Now it works, thanks!